# JavaFX. Open a pop-up window before main

Tags: java, events, javafx, popup, window

I have tried searching for this many times with no luck. I am writing a software where I want the user to input their resolution before moving on to the main UI, as the main UI will change size based on the resolution given. How would I open a popup window *without a button event handler* and then proceed to the main application?

Comment: Just open it in the `start()` method, and open the main window when it closes....

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Fastest reply I have gotten on this website. I apologise if this sounded like a dumb question; I am new to JavaFX (coming from SWT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open the popup window in your `start()` method:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // make sure application doesn't exit when we close the dialog window:
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        Stage popup = new Stage();
        TextField resolutionField = new TextField();
        // ... populate popup, etc...

        popup.setOnHidden(() -> {

            int resolution = Integer.parseInt(resolutionField.getText());

            // now create main UI...

            primaryStage.show();
        });

        popup.show();
    }
}
```